# How to addTarget (handleInputModeList) into SwiftUI Button

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikeyboard, custom-keyboard

I've been trying to make a custom keyboard within SwiftUI. The instructions about creating a custom keyboard, primarily written in UIKit causing some struggles with my SwiftUI code in configuration to fundamental buttons (Delete, Space and NextKeyboard).

I want to add this target to the SwiftUI Button, Is there any legit way to do it.

UIKit

```
@IBOutlet var nextKeyboardButton: UIButton!
self.nextKeyboardButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleInputModeList(from:with:)), for: .allTouchEvents)
```

SwiftUI

```
struct KeyBoardView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
                   //What should I add to this action in order to perform like above UIKit code
                   }, label: {Image(systemName:"globe").imageScale(.large)})
                }
             }
```

Thank you in advance as a part of the SwiftUI community!

Comment: make a different function and call from the action.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue, using `textDocumentProxy.insertText` doesn't do a single thing. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: Trying to figure this out in 2024 :')

Answer (score 1):

use: self.advanceToNextInputMode()

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing the `advanceToNextInputMode()` function from the ViewController helps to change to the next keyboard.

```swift
struct SwiftUIView: View {
   //callback called in ViewController to utilize keyboard change
    var callback: (() -> Void)?

    var body: some View {

        HStack(alignment: .center) {
        // button action expected to change the keyboard
            Button(action: {
              // callback created on button action
                callback?()
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "keyboard")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 25)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

KeyboardViewController where SwiftUIView is used inside viewDidLoad of the ViewController

```swift
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // callback received 
        let swiftUIView = SwiftUIView(callback: { [weak self] in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                print("Callback from SwiftUI view received")
                //function called to change keyboard
                self.advanceToNextInputMode()
               
                
            })
        let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: swiftUIView)
        
        addChild(hostingController)
        view.addSubview(hostingController.view)
        hostingController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        hostingController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        hostingController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        hostingController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        hostingController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        hostingController.didMove(toParent: self)
        
    }
```